# Automatic array length in Fortran and Visual Studio debug

Tags: arrays, visual-studio, debugging, fortran

I got a question concerning the debugging of a fortran file. Thus I declared it with d(*) automaticaly. However during the debugging and the supervision of the array it just shows the first number of the according array and not the 60 others.
(I use Fortran 95 compiler and Visual Studio 2010)

How can I still view all variables of the array?

---

Okay here comes one example for the code:

ia is a variable integer from the main routine depending on some input parameters.

```
subroutine abc(ia,a,b,c)
dimension d(*)

a = d(ia+1)
b = d(ia+2)
c = d(ia+3)

return 
end
```

However for debugging it is useful to know the endities of d(*)

Comment: I do not understand what you really did, I only guess. Show us some code. Note that the (*), so called assumed size arrays do not automatically set the size of the array in any way.

Comment: You don't need to include signature in your post - your user card is added automatically. Read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) for more details.

Comment: Since you have to provide the array size somehow (e.g. in an additional argument), you can use adjustable arrays. Instead of `REAL d(*)` use `REAL d(nsize)` where `nsize` is an `INTEGER` argument, in which you pass the true size of `d` in number of elements (`REAL` here is just an example data type). Then the debugger should be able to show you the content of the whole array.

Comment: +1 for using a language for real programmers :-)

Comment: Next time I must enough general tags to get more votes for an "exotic" language.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've found to do this is to use the `Watch` window and add a watch for the array elements.  Suppose your array is called `d`, then I've found that watching the following expressions shows the values in the array:

```
d(2)      ! which just shows the 2nd element in the array
d(1:10)   ! which shows the first 10 elements of the array
d(1:12:2) ! which shows the odd numbered elements of the array from 1 to 11
```

And of course, for an array of length 60 such as you suggest you have, then the expression

```
d(61)
```

will show you what value is in the memory location to which that array address points.

Of course, you should really be declaring your array as `d(:)`.  If you do, then the VS debugger shows the entire array in the usual `Locals` window.

Comment: Automatic arrays are local arrays, not dummy arguments.

Comment: Otherwise +1, assumed shape arrays will be better, because the subroutine knows the array size. OP didn't show any code so one can only guess that he talks about procedure arguments.

Comment: Adjustable arrays are also an option when one does not really want to "pollute" old F77 code with Fortran 90+ features (please, spare me the discussion about "no such thing as pure F77 compiler, they all implement one or another feature that later become part of F90" and so on)